# I cannot switch to root password

Tags: command-line

i have given '$' as one of the charectors in between the pasword for logging in my computer 
so when i have logged on to the terminal and wanted to shift to user it was giving 
su authentication faliure
but when i tried to install it (The su command) it was already installed 
plz help me to shift to the root

Answer (score 1):

Root account by default is disabled in Ubuntu, but you can log in to root with your `sudo` password through `sudo -i`

Comment: @kos  yes, that's the same in Ubuntu, , so `-H` flag shouldn't be necessary , at least in this case

Comment: Which makes sense after all :) +1